# Image Loading on Mobile CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have been editing a web page, some CSS/HTML (didn't start to code from the beginning just edit)

My website works with all browsers right now, the problem is half of the images does not upload on mobile. I have put a screenshot.

[image: Loading problem on mobile]

```
Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/2gj9b2ub/
```

I've been reding these media queries but it seems I have to re-write the all CSS for that? The site is not a mess just image uploading problem so maybe I can fix with something else.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Include your code here aswell, we should never have to leave stackoverflow to help, it should be optional only.

Comment: @Jonast92 it is very long more then 30k lines stackoverflow doesn't alow. Sorry =/

Comment: you must be able to find out what's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution after few research,

I just entered this one line of code `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.33, maximum-scale=1" />` into head section, adjusted scale and it worked. It doesn't work as good as like bootstrap or a code for designed for mobile, but it fixed.

Thanks for help.